# Sharepoint 2013 workflow - HttpSend action is unable to deserialize JSON data

Tags: json, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create workflow (`sharepoint 2013` for `o365`) which will send an email to document uploader manager.

For that I've created custom activity in `VS 2012` which should return uploader profile, from where I'd like to extract manager login.

I'm using for that `HttpSend` action and following `REST` service:

```
uri + "_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + Login + "'"
```

Response is okay - I've intercepted it with fiddler and I'm able to parse it with any `JSON parser` (including bulit-in into Fiddler)

```
{"d":{"__metadata":         {"id":"http://sp13dev/sites/dev/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)","uri":"http://sp13dev/sites/dev/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)","type":"SP.UserProfiles.PersonProperties"},"AccountName":"MVO\\mvogelsi","DirectReports":{"results":[]},"DisplayName":"Marcin Vogelsinger","Email":null,"ExtendedManagers":{"results":["MVO\\rmakowsk"]},"ExtendedReports":{"results":["MVO\\mvogelsi"]},"IsFollowed":false,"LatestPost":null,"Peers":{"results":["MVO\\tbiolo"]},"PersonalUrl":"http://sp13dev/my/Person.aspx?accountname=MVO%5Cmvogelsi","PictureUrl":null,"Title":null,"UserProfileProperties":   {"results":[{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"UserProfile_GUID","Value":"b3d09b4d-0d7e-45be-a3d9-b9f23a972e9c","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SID","Value":"S-1-5-21-28665521-4166225307-422210891-1000","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"ADGuid","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"AccountName","Value":"MVO\\mvogelsi","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"FirstName","Value":"Marcin","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PhoneticFirstName","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"LastName","Value":"Vogelsinger","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PhoneticLastName","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"PreferredName","Value":"Marcin Vogelsinger","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PhoneticDisplayName","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"WorkPhone","Value":"888265520","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Department","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Title","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-JobTitle","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Department","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Manager","Value":"MVO\\rmakowsk","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"AboutMe","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"PersonalSpace","Value":"SPSSITEERROR","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"PictureURL","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"UserName","Value":"mvogelsi","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"QuickLinks","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"WebSite","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"PublicSiteRedirect","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Dotted-line","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Peers","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Responsibility","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-SipAddress","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-MySiteUpgrade","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ProxyAddresses","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-HireDate","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-DisplayOrder","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ClaimID","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ClaimProviderID","Value":"Windows","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ClaimProviderType","Value":"Windows","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-SavedAccountName","Value":"MVO\\mvogelsi","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-SavedSID","Value":"System.Byte[]","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ResourceSID","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ResourceAccountName","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-ObjectExists","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-MasterAccountName","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-UserPrincipalName","Value":"mvogelsi@mvo.dom","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PersonalSiteCapabilities","Value":"0","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-O15FirstRunExperience","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PersonalSiteInstantiationState","Value":"8197","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-DistinguishedName","Value":"CN=Marcin Vogelsinger,CN=Users,DC=mvo,DC=dom","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-SourceObjectDN","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-FeedIdentifier","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"WorkEmail","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"CellPhone","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Fax","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"HomePhone","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Office","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Location","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"Assistant","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PastProjects","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Skills","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-School","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Birthday","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-StatusNotes","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-Interests","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-HashTags","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-EmailOptin","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PrivacyPeople","Value":"False","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-PrivacyActivity","Value":"0","ValueType":"Edm.String"},{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.KeyValue"},"Key":"SPS-TimeZone","Value":"","ValueType":"Edm.String"}]},"UserUrl":"http://sp13dev:80/my/Person.aspx?accountname=MVO%5Cmvogelsi"}}
```

I've used this custom activity within simple workflow created with sp designer 2013 and deployed in my dev environment.
But when trying to launch the workflow, it gets cancelled and following error appears:

```
Details: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Unable to deserialize HTTP response content. Expected ContentType : 'application/json', 'text/plain' or 'text/html', Received ContentType : 'application/json'. Content (truncated) : '{"d":{"__metadata":{"id":"http://sp13dev/sites/dev/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)","uri":"http://sp13dev [here goes the rest of JSON which is already available above]
```

Since it's for o365 i need to go declarative way.

Has anyone met such issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in past, and came across a blog which helped me fixing the same

> The reason for the issue is, by default response from SharePoint REST
>   is in XML and SharePoint designer workflow not able to parse the xml
>   and needs JSON response. To resolve this issue we need to pass Accept
>   and Content-Type as application/json;odata=verbose to request headers.
>   This way we will get JSON response.

https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/tag/expected-content-type-applicationjson/

Try the steps mentioned in the above blog.